# Wordpress links/bookmarks - need to urlencode because spaces are getting stripped

Tags: links, bookmark

Wordpress is stripping spaces out of links.

For example putting this into the web address of a new link:

```
mailto:my@email.com?subject=Hello there
```

and saving results in this:

```
mailto:my@email.com?subject=Hellothere
```

I know that a space is `%20` but my clients can't be expected to use this. Plus they may be uploading PDFs/Word documents with spaces in the filename and copying and pasting the link.

How can I remedy this? I know I have to use urlencode, however I don't really want to edit the core wordpress admin, because on upgrading I'll have to change it again. However, I will do if its the only way (having a look I can't seem to find a hook or anything that will let me do this!), but I just can't figure out where to put it.

Thanks for any/all help you can give me.

Comment: That's because the link you've given is invalid. You need to write spaces as `%20` or `+`. There is not much one can do about. And don't urlencode the links, because the `?` therein will get encoded as well for example. That would be counter-productive.

Comment: I understand, but my client doesn't want to have to type %20 every time they want a space. :)

Comment: instead of urlencode (I take your point) I could use `preg_replace("/ /","%20",$theurl);`

Comment: I see, look what you can do about that. As invalid URLs are not expected to be valid, you need to look if and especially how you can turn an invalid URL into a valid one. But you've not given any specs which strategy you want to use for it. Urlencoding the whole input looks not promising in my eyes.

Comment: Maybe you want to offer some comfortable dialog where you can enter the type of link (website, email) and the based on the type offer multiple fields (like subject for email) the user can enter values into? That dialog can then create the valid URL.

Comment: Just seeing your suggestion: why not, looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `antispambot()` function for this.

Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo antispambot('mailto:my@email.com?subject=Hello there'); ?>">Some link text</a>
```

Comment: ah, you've misinterpreted unfortunately. this is the actual links section in the backend...